# extracting xmltype in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype

I'm new in pl/sql and to start working with `xmltype` i followed this example on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml24.htm

It looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE Xml_tab ( xmlval xmltype);

INSERT INTO Xml_tab VALUES (
xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>
           <EMP>
              <EMPNO>221</EMPNO>
              <ENAME>John</ENAME>
           </EMP>'));

INSERT INTO Xml_tab VALUES (
xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>
           <PO>
              <PONO>331</PONO>
              <PONAME>PO_1</PONAME>
           </PO>'));

-- now extract the numerical values for the employee numbers

SELECT e.xmlval.extract('//EMPNO/text()').getNumVal() as empno
    FROM Xml_tab 
    WHERE e.xmlval.existsnode('/EMP/EMPNO')  = 1;
```

When I'm able to create table and insert rows into it. But when i try to run last procedure i get `ORA-22950: cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method`

Why is it happening? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you were trying to achieve, but this is how `EXTRACT`  and `EXISTSNODE` function could be used to retrieve numerical values for the employee numbers - `EMPNO`

```
SELECT extract(xmlval,'/EMP/EMPNO/text()').getNumberVal() as empno
    FROM Xml_tab WHERE
    existsnode(xmlval,'/EMP/EMPNO')  = 1 ;
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/live/PGP56960)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Unfortunatelly when i try your code i get `Only LOB or String Storage is supported in Thin XMLType` . And i fixed the link

Comment: @lidjan1 : It seems to work for me as I've shown you in the demo. It seems you are hiding some part of your code.  And the link that you are referring to Oracle9i . Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: try this: extract(xmlval,'/EMP/EMPNO/text()').getNumberVal() as empno

Comment: @hekko : Thanks. I've included it.

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak i believie im using 11g. That would explain much.

Comment: i think docs has typo: table without alias "e" and getNumVal() should read getNumberVal() even for 9i. Also work:  SELECT e.xmlval.extract('//EMPNO/text()').getNumberVal() as empno FROM Xml_tab e WHERE e.xmlval.existsnode('/EMP/EMPNO')  = 1;